# Trigger a second ajax function when the first has completed

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

Ok so im trying to start an ajax call after the first call has completed.  I have a form with 3 drop down menus.  The first menu onload runs the script to bring back values.  I then want to feed the vale into the second script and run the script to populate the second 3rd menu.

the second dropdown is populated onChange of the first.  This works great.  I then want the result of that feed into to third drop down.  I know my external queries are right I just think the ajax is wrong.  Here is my Ajax calls....

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#networks').trigger('change');
});




function get_cities(networks)
{
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "select.php", 
   beforeSend:  function () {
  $("#folder").html("<option>Loading ...</option>");
    },
   data: "idnetworks="+networks +"&par="+ <?php echo $row_rs_doc['parentid']; ?>,


   success: function(msg){
     $("#folder").html(msg);
   }



   });



} 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
jQuery('#folder').trigger('change');
});

function get_sub(folder)
{
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "select2.php", 
   beforeSend:  function () {
  $("#subfolder").html("<option>Loading ...</option>");
    },
   data: "iddocs="+folder,


   success: function(msg){
     $("#subfolder").html(msg);
   }



   });



} 
</script>
```

ok here are the form fields

```
<select name="networks" id="networks" onChange='get_cities($(this).val())'>
   <?php create(network, networkid, netname);?>
  </select>

<select name="folder" id="folder" onChange='get_sub($(this).val())'>


</select>

<select name="subfolder" id="subfolder">


</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KISS it. Just put the second ajax call inside the `success` of the first one

Answer (score 0):

You can use deferred objects, which will allow you to initiate additional actions without having to rewrite your existing event handler, and without nesting your code too much:

```
var req1 = $.ajax(...);

req1.done(function() { ... } );  // start your second request
```

Comment: thanks but I cant make either of those execute correctly Ive edited the post at the top to include the form fields

Comment: @DanielRobinson  please don't include your PHP - include the HTML output _after_ it has been through PHP.

Comment: my html output is blank as its an ajax call to a separate file.  Basically though the first and second list work great.  The 3rd list doesnt even try an load its just completely blank.  The function does not seem to run at all

Comment: @DanielRobinson my point was that you're expecting people to try and wade through your PHP source, when for a problem like this it's the _output_ of the PHP that matters.  You'll get more people looking at your question without the PHP.